# determine $rank(T)$ and $nullity(T)$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I've got the following problem.

**Problem**
For the following linear transformation $T:V\to W$ determine $rank(T)$ and $nullity(T)$ where $dim(V)=3$, $dim(W)=5$ and $T$ is one-to-one.

I'm not sure that my solution which follows is exact, any advice would be appreciated.

**My solution**
Since $T$ is one-to-one, $T$ maps every vector in $V$ into the image under ${T}$ of the vectors in $V$ so it must have the property $rank(T)={dim(image(T)) = 3}$ and because ${rank(T)+nullity(T)=dim(V)}$ we have $rank(T)=3$ and $nullity(T)=0$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $T$ is one-to-one, one concludes that $\ker(T) = \{0\}$ (why?). Consequently, $\dim(\ker(T)) = 0$.

Due to the Rank-Nullity theorem, it is possible to conclude that
\begin{align*}
\dim(V) = \dim(\ker(T)) + \operatorname{rank}(T) = 0 + \operatorname{rank}(T) \Rightarrow \operatorname{rank}(T) = \dim(V) = 3 
\end{align*}

Hopefully this helps!

Comment: This does help, thank you.

Comment: @MichaelWalker you are welcome! I am glad to help.

Answer (score 1):

You can go also the other way, since you know $T$ is one to one, you also know the dimension of $Ker(T)$ which is $dim(Ker(T)) = 0$, from there you can use the Rank-Nullity theorem and you conclude the same as you do before. It's just another perspective!

Comment: This makes sense, thank you.